# jaxb xmlelement marshalling with custom attributes

Tags: java, jaxb

trying to map my class to xml and add custom attributes.

```
public class MyXmlMappings  {
    @XmlElement
    protected String username;
    @XmlElement
    protected String password;
    @XmlElement
    protected Integer age;
}
```

after marshalling to xml looks like something like this:

```
<myXmlMappings>
<username/>
<password/>
<age/>
</myXmlMappings>
```

I need to have xml like this:

```
<myXmlMappings>
<username type="String" defaultValue="hello" />
<password type="String" defaultValue="asdf" />
<age type="Integer" defaultValue="25" />
</myXmlMappings>
```

As you can see I added type and defaultValue attributes. How can I add them to myXmlMappings class to be visible after marshalling?

Adding extra fields to myXmlMappings class is not viable I would like to do it somehow with annotations.

Comment: Where do the default values come from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**XML Representation**

I would recommend the following XML representation:

```
<myXmlMappings>
    <xmlMapping name="username" type="String" defaultValue="hello" />
    <xmlMapping name="password" type="String" defaultValue="asdf" />
    <xmlMapping name="age" type="Integer" defaultValue="25" />
</myXmlMappings>
```

**Java Model**

With the following Java model:

***XmlMappings***

```
@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class MyXmlMappings  {
    @XmlElement(name="xmlMapping")
    protected List<XmlMapping> xmlMappings;

}
```

***XmlMapping***

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class XmlMapping {
    @XmlAttribute
    protected String name;
    @XmlAttribute
    protected String type;
    @XmlAttribute
    protected String defaultValue;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
public class MyXmlMappings {

    @XmlPath("username/@type")
    protected String userType;
    @XmlPath("password/@type")
    protected String passwordType;
    @XmlPath("age/@type")
    protected String ageType;
    @XmlPath("username/@defaultValue")
    protected String userDefaultValue;
    @XmlPath("password/@defaultValue")
    protected String passwordDefaultValue;
    @XmlPath("age/@defaultValue")
    protected Integer ageDefaultValue;
    @XmlElement
    protected String username;
    @XmlElement
    protected String password;
    @XmlElement
    protected Integer age;
}
```

Comment: +1 - This solution leverages the `@XmlPath` extension in EclipseLink JAXB (MOXy):  http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/07/xpath-based-mapping.html